# Javascript - Getting caller arguments?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have similiar code to this

```
function Detail(id){
   var data=DataLoadMethod(id);
   bootbox.dialog({
   // whatever
   });
}
```

Now I need to find out which function opened bootbox dialog, which is pretty simple, BUT I also need to know what was the id argument value (inside bootbox dialog function - without passing it along/editing all functions) - is it possible to find out somehow?

Another approach can be saving last called function name with its arguments somewhere, so is it possible to have some piece of code that will by automatically called before every JS function execution?

Thanks for any ideas or help!

Comment: Can you clarify where, in your example, you need to know what `id` is? Is it in your bit marked `whatever`, or in the call to `DataLoadMethod` or somewhere else?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited it a bit.. I need to know inside bootbox dialog function to add data-caller (done) and data-externalId to dialog div so I can do some things with it later

Comment: Have you tried just using `id`? It should be in the closure.

Comment: The variable `id` is already available within that bit of code as it is within scope of the closure.

Comment: Yes thats correct if I would need to write it directly inside bootbox.dialog({}) function. That one has its definition inside bootbox.js script - exports.dialog = function(options) {} and thats the place where I need to do it so it changes every modal dialog I call. When I use arguments.callee.caller.toString() there I can see whole Detail function, but console.log(id) returns undefined variable ofcourse. Is it clear what I need to do or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be easy to add externalId property to bootbox dialog options and just pass it inside but I want to avoid that so Im trying to do it like this.